# AWS architecture - Web application (Diagram)

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, architecture

I am in the process of setting up a medium sized AWS infrastructure for a web project. I may be overthinking a couple things and therefore wanted to ask the community for opinions. Any input is appreciated.

**Please see the graphic:**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkqSE.png)

**Explanation (from left to right):**

1. My domain is hosted on GoDaddy and will simply route to Cloudfront in order to globally cache static content.
2. Cloudfront will point to Route53 which is responsible for routing the user to the closest region based on Geoprximity and/or Latency
3. Each region will have an availability load balancer pointing to an EC2 instance (different availability zones for disasters fallback)
4. From there, each EC2 instance writes to a single MySQL database. Static content is loaded from a S3 bucket.
5. This MySQL database replicates/synchronizes itself across availability zones and regions and creates read-replicas
6. If an EC2 instance has a read-request, it contacts another Route53 router that forwards the read-request to a load-balancer (in each region) based on where the request is coming from (geoproximity/latency). The only alternative I see here would be to directly point read-requests from a European EC2 instance to a European load-balancer. (vice versa for US)
7. The load-balancer in each region will then decide from which database to read based on health or amount of requests
8. Each EC2 instance can also trigger a LAMBDA function through an API Gateway.

What am I missing? Is this too much? What are the ups and downs of this construct?

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things look reasonable up to step 6.  There's no need to find the nearest MySQL database, because your instances already know where it is -- it's the one in the local region.

Step 7 is problematic because ELBs can't be used to balance RDS instances.  However, with Aurora/MySQL, you get a single cluster "reader" endpoint hostname with a short TTL that load balances across your Aurora replicas.  If a replica dies, it's removed from DNS automatically.

Step 8 it's not strictly necessary to use API Gateway -- instances can directly invoke Lambda functions through the Lambda API.

Additionally, there's Lambda@Edge that allows triggering Lambda functions directly from CloudFront -- although if the Lambda function you need is large in size (dependencies) or needs to run inside a VPC, you have to cascade two of them -- the edge function (not in VPC) invokes the regional function (large, or in a VPC) -- but this is still typically less expensive than API Gateway.  Edge functions automatically replicate globally and run in the region closest to the CloudFront edge handling the individual request, and within any given function invocation this can be identified by inspecting `process.env.AWS_REGION`.  Edge functions can also be used to change the origin serving the content -- so, e.g. if your function sees that it's been invoked in an EU region, it can rewrite the request so that CloudFront will send S3 requests to an EU bucket.

If your site is at the apex of a domain, e.g. `example.com` rather than, say, `www.example.com`, your domain will need to be hosted in Route 53, not Go Daddy, because constraints in the DNS standards do not allow the dynamic behavior required by CloudFront at the apex.  You can still have your domain registered with them, but not hosted by them.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is great input. I guess point 7 and 8 are clear now. However, I do have a follow up on point 6. If I remove the Route53 that is supposed to route the db read-request, wouldn't I have multiple endpoints for the read-replicas? If so, that would require me to change the code just for the EU region to read from the EU read-replica endpoint, correct?

Comment: Code can discover the region it's running in from the instance metadata service, and so know which endpoint to use.

Comment: Thanks Michael...will keep your email close ;-)